# Is it possible to open the iOS app by means of a remote notification?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I need to open the app and show the user that a request is coming his way. Based on that, he may receive a phone call from my server (not VoIP though).

My requirement is similar to what happens during a VoIP call. Just that we won't necessarily be using VoIP. At least not right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, iOS doesn't permit opening apps via remote notification.

What you get is the user can select a notification on their lock screen to unlock the phone then open the app.

Answer (score 0):

No. User has to click on notification to open the app.

You can not open the app directly on the remote notification receiving.